# Run node-webkit project in Netbeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans, ide, node-webkit

I am trying to configure Netbeans IDE 7.4 for node-webkit development.

It is excellent IDE but I want to run my projects with F6 button. To do this I added NW.EXE as additional browser (executable is located outside project folder).

After this I have a problem with execution arguments. NW.EXE expects a folder path to be specified as an argument, but I cannot leave empty field of Start File in project settings  and the Project URL has to start with either `http://` or `file://` while Node-webkit needs a path like `C:/path_to_app`

Does any method exist to deal with this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can work this around by creating a batch program and let it strip the file name down to the path name part, to be fed to `nw.exe`, as it requires.

Unfortunately, as you said, we don't have full control over the way the main file of the project is passed to the browser, hence some further actions (in addition to the creation of the batch file) are needed.

This is how I got it working after a bit of struggle:

- added `nw.exe` to the system `%PATH%` variable (optional, just for ease of access)
- created `nw.bat` in the same folder as `nw.exe`, and filled it with this content:

  ```
  @echo %1
  start nw.exe %~d1%~p1
  ```

The first line of this batch file is just to inspect the actual parameter that is getting passed to the batch file.

The second line uses `start` to invoke `nw.exe` without having to wait for its return (you may need to specify the full path to `nw.exe`, if you didn't add it to the system `%PATH%` variable).

The second line also passes to `nw.exe` the drive part of the parameter (extracted from `%1` by `%~d1`) concatenating it to the path of the parameter (extracted from `%1` by `%~p1`).

For instance, my last run from within NetBeans gave this output:

```
D:\node\test\index.html
D:\node\test>start nw.exe D:\node\test\
```

Then I needed something to tie the NetBeans run button to an arbitrary executable, and luckily I found a perfect fit.

So here is how I went on:

- installed the **Node.js Projects** plugin from [Timboudreau Update Center](http://timboudreau.com/modules)
- went to `Options > Miscellaneous > Node.js` and set the `Node.js Binary` field to point to my `nw.bat` file

In my project, I've also taken care to put `package.json` in the same folder of `index.html` (being that that's the main file of my package, and that's what will be fed to the batch file).

Now pressing F6 on my NetBeans installation happily runs my node-webkit project without any further ado :-)